# Basic authentication external rest api from jQquery

Tags: c#, jquery, api, rest

I have a problem accessing an external api from a single page app I'm trying to build.

I can login to it from Postman with username and password, and then I got a AuthenticationTicket I can use for the personal data for the second request.

When I try login from the app I got "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I can't get it to work with jsonp since it has to post the logindata?!

```
        $.ajax
        ({
          beforeSend: function (x) {
          x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic Username=x&Password=y');
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://test.com/api/login/",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function () {
            alert('you're in!');
        }

    });
```

response from api in Postman:

```
AuthenticationTicket → x
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →52
Content-Type →application/json; 
charset=utf-8
Date →Sun, 05 Jan 2014 20:29:36 GMT
Expires →-1
LogoutKey → x
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SessionTicket → x
X-AspNet-Version → X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By → X-Powered-By
Specifies the technology (ASP.NET, PHP, JBoss, e.g.) supporting the web application (version details are often in X-Runtime, X-Version, or X-AspNet-Version) ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course, C# fixes the deal.

```
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://url.com/api/login/?param=value&param2=value");
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Username:Password"));
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a dataType of JSONP:

```
 dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Comment: then I get Status Code:400 Bad Request